# How do I call a specific overridden method from an inherited method in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, overriding, overloading

I have a class named `LotteryTicket` that have 3 subclasses: `Pick4`, `Pick5`, and `Pick6`. I want to be able to call a method `public void pickNumbers()`where once called, will be able to recognize which LotteryTicket subclass is being used and ask for the appropriate amount of arguments (i.e. calling `pickNumbers()` in an instance of `Pick5` will ask for 5 ints).

I've attempted to get around this by providing `public void pick4Numbers(int firstPick, int secondPick, int thirdPick, int fourthPick)` for 4, 5, and 6 in the `LotteryTicket` class, and having the `pickNumbers()` method call the appropriate method (which will get overridden) based on a field `pickAmount`. Unfortunately, this  would entail having to provide arguments.

Here is the `LotteryTicket` class:

```
public class LotteryTicket
{
protected int pickAmount;
protected boolean isRandom;
protected ArrayList<Integer> numbersPicked;
protected Date datePurchased;
protected SimpleDateFormat sdf;

public LotteryTicket(int pickAmount, boolean isRandom)
{
    // INITIALIZATION OF VARIABLES
    this.pickAmount = pickAmount;
    this.isRandom = isRandom;

    // CONSTRUCTION OF ARRAYLIST
    numbersPicked = new ArrayList(pickAmount);

}

/**
 * The number pick method for ALL subclasses. Running this method will run the appropriate pickxNumbers
 * method, where x is the pickAmount.
 *
 */
public void pickNumbers()
{
    if(pickAmount == 4){
        pick4Numbers(int firstPick, int secondPick, int thirdPick, int fourthPick)
    }
    if(pickAmount == 5){
        pick5Numbers(int firstPick, int secondPick, int thirdPick, int fourthPick, int fifthPick)
    }
    if(pickAmount == 6){
        pick6Numbers(int firstPick, int secondPick, int thirdPick, int fourthPick, int fifthPick, int sixthPick)
    }
}

/**
 * The number pick method for the Pick4 subclass.
 *
 */
public void pick4Numbers(int firstPick, int secondPick, int thirdPick, int fourthPick)
{

}
```

`Pick4` class:

```
public class Pick4 extends LotteryTicket
```

{

```
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Pick4
 */
public Pick4(boolean isRandom)
{
    super(4, isRandom);
}

/**
 * Overloaded pick4Numbers() method. Depending on the ticket type, the amount of picks will vary.
 * For example, Pick4 tickets will only ask for 4 int values, Pick5 tickets will ask for 5, etc.
 * 
 *@param int firstPick
 *@param int secondPick
 *@param int thirdPick
 *@param int fourthPick
 */
public void pick4Numbers(int firstPick, int secondPick, int thirdPick, int fourthPick)
{
    numbersPicked.add(new Integer(firstPick));
    numbersPicked.add(new Integer(secondPick));
    numbersPicked.add(new Integer(thirdPick));
    numbersPicked.add(new Integer(fourthPick));
}
```

Comment: Accept varargs `public void pick(int... args)` and throw IllegalArgumentException if number is not valid

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: @ChetanKinger if OP declared `pick5Numbers` and `pick6Numbers` as they said, why not?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou `if(pickAmount == 4){
        pick4Numbers(int firstPick, int secondPick, int thirdPick, int fourthPick)
    }`.

Comment: Where come the pick values from? (`firstPick`, `secondPick`, ...)

Comment: @ChetanKinger No, not the way it was. I left it like that so you guys could see my thought process behind the code, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it would be better to do like this:

```
public class LotteryTicket {
   protected int pickAmount;
   protected boolean isRandom;
   protected List<Integer> numbersPicked;
   protected Date datePurchased;
   protected SimpleDateFormat sdf;

   protected int[] numbersToPick;

   //To create random valued ticket
   public LotteryTicket(int pickAmount) {
      this.pickAmount = pickAmount;
      isRandom = true;
   }

   //To create specified valued ticket
   public LotteryTicket(int... numbersToPick) {
      pickAmount = numbersToPick.length;
      isRandom = false;
      this.numbersToPick = numbersToPick;
   }

   public void pickNumbers() {
      numbersPicked = new ArrayList<>(pickAmount);
      if (isRandom) {
         Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
         for (int i = 0; i < pickAmount; i++) {
            numbersPicked.add(random.nextInt());
         }
      } else {
         for (int i = 0; i < pickAmount; i++) {
            numbersPicked.add(numbersToPick[i]);
         }
      }
   }

}
```

And Pick4, Pick5 ... etc will be like this:

```
public class Pick4 extends LotteryTicket {

   //For random valued ticket  
   public Pick4() {
      super(4);
   }
   //For specified valued ticket    
   public Pick4(int pick1, int pick2, int pick3, int pick4) {
      super(pick1, pick2, pick3, pick4);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend from `LotteryTicket`, make `pickNumbers()` method abstract and accepting `List` or varargs:

```
public abstract class LotteryTicket {
   //...
   abstract public void pickNumbers(int... numbers);
   //...
}
```

then in implementation classes, e. g. `Pick4`:

```
public class Pick4 extends LotteryTicket {
   //...
   @Override
   public void pickNumbers(int... numbers) {
       if (numbers.length != 4) 
           throw IllegalArgumentException("For Pick4, there must be exactly 4 numbers!");
       for (int n : numbers) {
           numbersPicked.add(n); // no need in explicit boxing, Java will do it for you
       }
   }
}
```